# Retrieve product and product stock from salable products of ALL stores (like in backend)

Tags: product, catalog, backend

We want to retrieve all products and their stock using a script. This is the code we run. But this shows only the products of the store domain (url) that we use to request the file.

**question:** How can we remove the (automatic) store filter? and retrieve **all** the products of the magento installations (just like catalog products overview in backend?

```
Mage::app();

$data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('cost')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you emulate the admin-store like this:

```
// emulate the admin store to be able to save entities
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// get collection here, current store and flat catalog data won't apply

// end admin store emulation
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

Comment: yes thanks tried that, no luck ``` Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in pp/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php:816  ```

Comment: I have the idea that      ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) is auto-adding the storeid filter as well (but how it knows which I am in is a mystery)

Comment: @your error: I am not sure, but this looks as if you are filtering or selecting an attribute that doesn't exist. I assume "stock_type" is one of your custom attributes, do you also have "stock_status"? Also, can you try with "addAttributeToFilter('visibility....." instead of "addFieldToFilter(..."?

Comment: thanks this was it! Only now - how do I add the filter "stock_type" again? ->addAttributeToFilter('stock_type', array('like' => '%Stock Article%'))

Comment: What is "stock_type"? I don't think it is Magento standard?

Comment: It's an custom product attribute text value

Comment: Hm, I am not sure. Are you using flat catalogs? Maybe you should post another question to get an answer.

Comment: yes flat - am searching too. Nothing specific found for ADMIN_STORE_ID env .. and thanks for your help!